# Any free tool for SQL server log recovery<SQL 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

By mistake I have updated all the rows of a table with same data for certain columns (missed the statement that contains where clause). Are there any free tools that can help me to restore old data for these rows.

Answer (score 0):

If the recovery model is full then it is possible to go back in time. Other than that, I don't think it's possible to recover that data. Unless you backup your data regularly.

See [How to: Restore to a Point in Time (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx)